# selenium executeScript hangs on IE

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

OK folks, I've searched the web for 2 days to solve the modal dialog problem. Great information out there and it all works except for IE. I'm trying to open a file upload dialog and select a new file. I created autoIT scripts and they work just fine with FF and Chrome.  When I try with IE the "executeScript" does not return back to my test scripts. In IE the "file upload" dialog is opened. But That is where my scripts stops. If I manually run the autoIT script, it returns back to the test script after the "file upload" dialog closes.

```
//WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
// processPage(driver);
WebDriver ieDriver =new InternetExplorerDriver();
processPage(ieDriver);
// WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
// processPage(chromeDriver);
```

.
.
. other code
.
.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name(uploadDifferntFile));
if (driver instanceof InternetExplorerDriver) {
  ((InternetExplorerDriver) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

} else if(driver instanceof FirefoxDriver){
  ((FirefoxDriver) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

} else if(driver instanceof ChromeDriver){
  ((ChromeDriver) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

}
```

.
.
.  autoIT
.
.
.

```
try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(fileToExecute);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Failed to execute autoIT");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thank you for all your support

Comment: you do not need to click just set the input field to the file name you want to use.     `driver.findElement(By.id("nodeW73")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("nodeW73")).sendKeys("c:\\blank.docx");`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to modal dialog invoked during your argument[0].click operation in IE, see https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver, section "Clicking  Elements or Submitting Forms and alert()", I think it describes same issue.

Few options to try would be:

1. Replace your with JavaScript code with just "element.click()" or
   "element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)"
2. Start a new thread before you do
   argument[0].click, wait in that thread a bit and then run autoIt
   code

Also you can replace your existing code with JavascriptExecutor to write JavaSrcipt only once:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name(uploadDifferntFile));
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just stepped in the same problem, because sendKeys wasn't a stable solution for me working with Internet Explorer. So I build a variation with AutoIt.

For Firefox I use the JavaScript and for IE I do a doubleclick on the input field:

```
// fileInput is the WebElement resulting from the input field with type file
if (browser == "FF") {
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", fileInput);
} else {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    Action doubleClick = action.doubleClick(fileInput).build();
    doubleClick.perform();
}
```