# JavaScript Executor Click does not work properly on Internet explorer unless the IE 11 is resetted and Restored and the computer is restarted

Tags: javascript, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-iedriver

When not functioning properly - it will execute the javascript click and i see the button being clicked. But the line that i am printing in next line of my code using  System.print will not print anything. It looks like it is getting somewhere lost after clicking the button and not coming out of the javascript click method.

But the interesting part is that - if i reset the IE and restart my computer - it starts to work and prints the next line and everything gets executed.

This issue started happening recently like a week ago and i tried to revert the updates - security ones from microsoft but no luck.

I also tried using different versions of IE driver starting from the latest one upto the 8 previous versions.

This issue starts arising very randomly. It happened like 4 times in a week and i have to reset the browser and restart my pc in order to get my tests execute.

Here is my code;

```
public void enteringValuesForAKMWithExistingTieNumber(AKMSimulatorTO akmto, String storedTieNumber)
{
customerName.sendKeys(akmto.getCustomerName());
customerTie.sendKeys(storedTieNumber);
List<WebElement> ls = getDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector("input"));

accountNumber.sendKeys(akmto.getAccountNumber());

javascriptExecutorClick(ls.get(3));
System.out.println("Button is clicked");
}

protected void javascriptExecutorClick(WebElement element) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) (getDriver());
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: A) Java != JavaScript B) no idea what you are asking C) when you have "not working code", please provide a [mcve] (we arent wizards here, we cant help with problems that you only vaguely explain to us).

Comment: Is there any question for us?

Comment: I will post my code. Sorry.

Comment: Javascript executor click works but will not execute the next sysout print line sometimes - This is when i will have to reset the browser and restart. And the same code will start working properly. Is that a problem with IE? @k29

Comment: Hard to tell without your machine or the webpage/HTML. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672440/selenium-executescript-hangs-on-ie